# Add ng-required attribute dynamically in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Currently I have defined my custom directive:

```
.directive('foo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

      scope.isRequired = function () {
        return !attributes.disabled; // more complicated test
      };

    }
  };
}])
```

And it's used like:

```
<input name="a" type="text" foo ng-required="isRequired" />
<input name="b" type="text" foo ng-required="isRequired" />
<input name="c" type="text" foo ng-required="isRequired" />
```

Is it possible to define `ng-required` attribute in the directive instead of linking the `isRequired` method in the template ?

Expected result:

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

  element.attr('ng-required', function () {
    return !attributes.disabled; // more complicated test
  });

}
```

However this function is not called, `ng-required` is not applied.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But what if you define a template for your directive, which have the ng-directive tag in it. The template will be evaluated and ng-required is applied then.

Comment: With this directive I'm adding extra validators to the `input` element. Also the field is set to disabled or not depending other checkbox field. When input is disabled I expect validators not to work, but form is still running validators on it. With `ng-required` binded with function that checks if field is disabled (and some extra checks) it works well. My point is to simplify `foo ng-required="isRequired"` statement and move `ng-required` definition directly to the directive and make template cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed you have an input which should be extended, you can do something like this:

```
<input ng-model="bar" foo />
```

and your directive:

```
.directive('foo', [function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {},
       template: '<input ng-required="isRequired" />',
       controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs){
          $scope.isRequired = function(){
              return !attributes.disabled; // more complicated test
          }
        }]
     };
 }]);
```

You can also bind additional attributes to your internal scope:

```
<input ng-model="bar" foo foo-required="somefunction" />
```

and in your directive:

```
scope: {
   requiredCallback: &fooRequired
}
```

Comment: I cannot use the `template` in this way. Directive can be also applied to the `textarea` and `select`.

Comment: @hsz hm, that is a problem, I'll take a look if there is a solution (have something in mind with $compile)

Comment: Simple calling `$compile(element)(scope);` at the end of `link` funcion causes browser crash.

Comment: what if we extract the generated html first, compile it and replace the existing element?